# ListPopupWindow jumps to top on certain devices when scrolled

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a search field using a ListPopupWindow. 
On certain devices the ListPopupWindow changes it's position when scrolled. (It jumps to the top):

Before scrolling:

[image]

After scrolling:

[image: Jumped to top after scrolling]

I tested this on a Nexus 6P.
On other devices it works normally, it does not change it's initial position when scrolled. This was captured on a Samsung Galaxy A5.

[image: Dropdown normal]

Here's the code:

The Activiyt:

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    EditText itemName;
    ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
    String[] items = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4",
            "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        itemName = (EditText) findViewById(
                R.id.item_name);
        listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(
                MainActivity.this);
        listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(
                MainActivity.this,
                R.layout.list_item, items));
        listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(itemName);
        listPopupWindow.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.MATCH_PARENT);
        listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);

        listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
        listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        itemName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listPopupWindow.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {
        itemName.setText(items[position]);
        listPopupWindow.dismiss();
    }
}
```

The layout file of the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText

        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter item name"
        android:textSize="26sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the list item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:padding="6dp"
          android:textSize="50sp"
          android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: to need to set layout according to screen sizes.

Comment: could you provide some code so I can see what you mean? :)

Comment: you mean search is showing in only one device and not on other devices?

Comment: No, The list (ListPopupWindow) is showing on both devices. But on the Nexus 6P is jumps to the top of the screen when scrolled (shown in the first picture - the edittext is no longer visible). On the Samsung however it stays below the edittext even when scrolled and I would like to have this behavior also on the Nexus.

Comment: I added a picture with how it looks before scrolling on the Nexus

Comment: zip code and share so that i can check..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161803/discussion-between-shivam-oberoi-and-buellas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

you have to set the height of your `listPopupWindow` explicitly. In order to do this, you need to calculate the available height and find the right moment for setting that value.

1. Get rid of the above line.
2. Add this to your xml `LinearLayout`:

   ```
   android:id="@+id/root"
   ```
3. Add this to your `MainActivity`:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
       super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
       if (hasFocus) {
           int popupHeight = findViewById(R.id.root).getHeight() - itemName.getHeight();
           listPopupWindow.setHeight(popupHeight);
       }
   }
   ```

Inside a fragment, you don't need `onWindowFocusChanged`. You can simply post a `Runnable` to the view:

```
Activity activity;
EditText itemName;
ListPopupWindow listPopupWindow;
LinearLayout linearLayout;
String[] items = {"Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6", "Item7", "Item8", "Item9", "Item10"};

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof Activity) {
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    linearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.root);
    itemName = view.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    listPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(activity);
    listPopupWindow.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(activity, R.layout.list_item, items));
    listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(itemName);
    listPopupWindow.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.MATCH_PARENT);
    listPopupWindow.setModal(true);
    listPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    itemName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listPopupWindow.show();
        }
    });
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int popupHeight = linearLayout.getHeight() - itemName.getHeight();
            listPopupWindow.setHeight(popupHeight);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved the problem :). How would you solve this if the list would be in a fragment?

Comment: Just the list? Or the `EditText`, too?

Comment: The EditText too

Comment: I also found a little problem with this solution. If the list has fewer items the dropdown will still go till the bottom of the screen.

Comment: That's another question (for which I do have an answer, too). To make an answer usable you should ask a new question or edit this one to encompass both, the situation when the `EditText` gets pushed out of the screen AND the situation when a short, but non-wrapped `ListPopupWindow` takes up the whole screen (below the `EditText`).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
val popup = ListPopupWindow(context)
try {
        val setListItemExpandMax: Method = popup.javaClass.getDeclaredMethod("setListItemExpandMax", Integer.TYPE)
        setListItemExpandMax.isAccessible = true
        setListItemExpandMax.invoke(popup, 5)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        when (e) {
            is NoSuchMethodException, is InvocationTargetException, is IllegalAccessException -> {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            else -> throw e
        }
    }
```